# "A, B, C + verb " vs "Having A, B, C...+ verb"? compound subject verb agreement vs gerund including as list verb agreement?

Tags: verb-agreement

According to compound subject -verb agreement, it seems I should use *is* in the following sentences. But I sense it's wrong I'm a bit little confused.

> - Having the same job all life long, the same habits, the same weekends **is** boring
> - Having the same job all life long, the same habits, the same weekends **are** boring

What is the verb agreeing with, in order to determine its form?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please visit [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I have a list after a single gerund, do I use "is" or "are"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333809/if-i-have-a-list-after-a-single-gerund-do-i-use-is-or-are)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is an example of *asyndeton,* where the conjunction *and* is deliberately omitted. We can put it back, moving the adverbial phrase as necessary:

> Having the same job **and** the same habits **and** the same weekends all life long...

This makes it easy to see that you have one collection of things you are "having". The construction (in terms of the question title) is simply *Having A*.

> Having the same job, the same habits, the same weekends all life long...

That fragment is a single thought: *Having A all life life long.*

Thus the verb is *is.*

It's possible to move the adverbial phrase and then add the extra items, as you did:

> Having the same job all life long, the same habits, the same weekends, **is** boring.

However, note the extra comma before the verb. You have inserted "the same habits, the same weekends" as a parenthetical addition: that needs a comma at the end. It may be that the original omission of that terminal comma caused the confusion because you end up with the plural *weekends* adjacent to the verb *is.* Correctly adding the comma removes that awkwardness.

Comment: When a compound subject contains both a singular and a plural noun or pronoun joined by or or nor, the verb should agree with the part of the subject that is nearer the verb....this refutes you answer!

Comment: @Sam I'm sure there are other questions about *or* (rather than *and,* as here).

Comment: When the subjects are joined by “and,” the verb agrees with the pronoun “they.” ..what about this?

Comment: I think you're confusing compound subjects and their verb ("A, B and C *go* to the beach"; uses the *they* form of the verb) and a list following a gerund as in this question, where the gerund is singular.

Comment: yes .you are absolutely right. thanks andrew..I''m getting ready for Toefl and I was really confused about this.

Comment: A gerund is an -ing verb that acts as a noun. When the gerund serves as the subject of the sentence, the verb should be singular, even if the object of the gerund is plural. the only points remain here is  plural form of gerund could you pls give me an example?

Comment: There isn't a plural form of a gerund. But a plural list like *Having A, B, and C* [or even *or C*] *means you can go to the beach* is possible. But *Having* there still takes the singular verb [*means*], as I explained in my answer.

Comment: so When the gerund serves as the subject of the sentence, the verb should be singular.in fact, we don't have any case the gerund as a subject takes plural verb?right?

Comment: That's right, yes. I suppose the answer could say that, now that we know what you're studying and have found so far.